# Set max amount of entries that can be stored in StorageMap

Tags: storagemap

I would like to know how I can set a threshold of 10 entries so that it's the maximum number of values that can be stored in a StorageMap structure.

My struct is the following:

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub type CoinStorage<T> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, AccountIdOf<T>, Coin, OptionQuery>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is the easiest to use a `CountedStorageMap` and check the number of entries before insertion, as the type itself does not enforce the limit.

Using a `StorageValue<_, BoundedBTreeMap` can be not ideal for parachains, since it will always load the whole value into the Proof, even when only a single element is accessed.
This implies that the number of elements must be configured to be conservatively low.

Answer (score 1):

you could store `BoundedBTreeMap` in `StorageValue`:

```rs
pub type CoinStorage<T> = StorageValue<_, BoundedBTreeMap<AccountIdOf<T>, Coin, ConstU32<32>>, OptionQuery>;
```

I think it would have the same complexity for insertion/deletion as `StorageMap` - O(logn)